# QueryList.changes.subscribe() does not get triggered in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, openlayers

I want to generate some containers for popups based on how many items received. The component is working as expected in dev and prod, but it is not working in the unit test, because the querylist.changes never emit. I have to call querylist.notifyChanges() as a workaround. The mapRef is an Openlayers map instance

HTML template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let id of currentDivs">
        <div class="popup" #popupContainer [id]="id"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
   @ViewChildren("popupContainer", { read: ElementRef })
   popupContainers: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>;

   ngOnInit(): void {
   //init map and other stuff...
    init();
   }
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.popupContainers.changes.subscribe(
                (containers: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
                    this._mapRef.getOverlays().clear();
                    containers.forEach((container) => {
                        //create overlay container for popup
                        const id = container.nativeElement.id;
                        if (!this._mapRef.getOverlayById(id)) {
                            const overlay = new Overlay({
                                id,
                                element: container.nativeElement,
                                autoPan: false,
                            });
                            this._mapRef.addOverlay(overlay);
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
  }

  init(): void {
  
   bService.getItems().subscribe((items) => {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
     divs = items.map((item) =>item.id);
     this.ngZone.run(() => {
       this.currentDivs = divs;
       this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
   });
  });
 }
```

Test code:

```
 beforeEach((done) => {
            aServiceSpy.getInfo.and.returnValue(of(infos));
            bServiceSpy.getItems.and.returnValue(of(items));
            fixture.detectChanges();

            component.mapRef.once("rendercomplete", () => {
                //I have to call notifyChanges() as a workaround 
                //component.popupContainers.notifyChanges() 
                done();
      });
  it("should populate popup",() => {
      console.log(component.popupContainers) 
      // it actually has length == items.length,
      //but component.popupContainers.changes in the actual code never emit
  })
 });
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using OnPush strategy though. Did you find a right way to deal with this?

Comment: I figuured out my problem was that I actually had a `delay` timer which stoped the queryList subscription.

Answer (score 0):

`querylist.changes` should be called automatically in Angular unit test when there is QueryList changes. Couple things should be aware of

1. make sure there is queried content changes after initialization. Seems like your test has never changed the content. You can add a `this.popupContainers.changes.pipe(startWith(this.popupContainers))` to always initialize the subscription.
2. I dont see your code has any timer that stops the `queryList` changes, just share my experience here. I had a `delay(0)` in my content query subscription and I ran `detectChanges` before the test which actually causes test ends before the subscription emits. So I put the `changeDetection` into the `fakeAsync` process solved my problem.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Create component etc initialize
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
  });
describe('test', fakeAsync(() => {
   // Test logic
}));
```

to

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Create component etc initialize
  });
describe('test', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
   // Test logic
}));
```